# Why my Clip Art in Android Studio some missing?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: this my icon in android studio]
Hello any one can help me,  i dont know what happen in my android studi after update to version 4.2.2 i try to make vector icon and **i found many clip art missing.**

Comment: What is missing?

Comment: many icon in my clip art sir

Comment: I am uncertain what you mean by "my clip art". Is there a specific icon that you believe to be missing? If you tell us what to look for, we can see if our Android Studio 4.2.2 installations do or do not have the missing icons.

Answer (score 4):

It seems Android Studio installation does not come with icons, it has to download them when you're on the popup.

Be aware though, **it's only downloading the icons / clip art when the "select icons" popup is open ! *If you close it it stops*.**

It takes quite a while to get them all but you have them eventually.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day! 

Comment: This is messed up, thought they only included 1/10 the icons after an update but yeah they appeared after waiting and reopening the menu. No hint that it's downloading